# php get manifest attributes from androidmanifest.xml

Tags: php, android, xml

I would like to get the versionName, versionCode and package name from the AndroidManifest.xml.
Here's what I have so far:

```
// Load AndroidManifest.xml
$xml = simplexml_load_string($manifest);

//print_r($xml);

list(,$versionCode) = each($xml->xpath('/manifest/@android:versionCode'));
list(,$versionName) = each($xml->xpath('/manifest/@android:versionName'));
list(,$package) = each($xml->xpath('(/manifest/@package)'));

echo "versionCode: ".$versionCode.", versionName: ".$versionName.", package:".$package."\n";
```

I wonder if there is a better way to get the values of those elements?

Sample AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"    package="com.example.bluetoothchat"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name">
      <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".BluetoothChat" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:label="@string/select_device" android:name=".DeviceListActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: How did you open the apk file for reading the manifest?

Comment: How do you get the app_name, since it is a reference from `Strings.xml`

Comment: @iSun AndroidManifest.xml is extracted using [AXMLPrinter2.jar](https://code.google.com/p/android4me/downloads/detail?name=AXMLPrinter2.jar&can=2&q=), first unzip apk file then go into the unzipped directory and run `java -jar AXMLPrinter2.jar AndroidManifest.xml`. @twlkyao I didn't have the need to get app name so don't have an answer sorry!

Answer (score 0):

**Check this is what the expected result**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('AndroidManifest.xml');
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
$versionName = $xml->xpath('/manifest/@android:versionName');
$versionCode =$xml->xpath('/manifest/@android:versionCode');
$package = $xml->xpath('/manifest/@package');
echo "VERSION NAME :".$versionName[0]->versionName."<br/>";
echo "VERSION CODE :".$versionCode[0]->versionCode."<br/>";
echo "VERSION PAC :".$package[0]->package."<br/>";
?>
```

Comment: thanks for posting.. unfortunately it failed: **PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity**

Comment: @t0x13 Check it out , now it won't through the Warning error,,, and before that you need to have your manifest file in the same directory..

Comment: It is not throwing an error anymore.. however the xpath doesnt seem to be working correctly on a different machine. My code doesnt work either now. It can grab the package, but the versionCode and versionName come back emtpy. Could it be due to different versions of php ?

Comment: which version of php ,,you are using

Comment: I should've mentioned it before.. It works on 5.3.3 but not on 5.2.6.. And from researching it looks to be a known problem with xpath and namespaces (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45553).

Comment: I think I have to register the namespace first to get it to work. But when I tried doing that it still didnt work.

Comment: `VERSION NAME :<br/>VERSION CODE :<br/>VERSION PAC :com.example.bluetoothchat<br`  It does not work

Comment: then how did you get VERSION PAC :com.example.bluetoothchat

Comment: i am using php 5.3.2 only ,, but it works for me without errors

Comment: The problem is with 5.2.6, it works fine on 5.3.3.. It outputs the package because it doesnt have a namespace, like android:versionCode

Comment: thats not namespace ,, attributes of <manifest>  .....finally what is your conclusion friend

Comment: Can you please explain me that how can I open an apk to read the manifest file from it?

Comment: @iSun sorry i am not a android developer!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the PHP XQuery extension to get the job done:

```
declare namespace android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";

let $manifest := (: your XML :)
return
 <ul>
  <li>{$manifest/@android:versionCode/string()}</li> 
  <li>{$manifest/@android:versionName/string()}</li>
  <li>{$manifest/@package/string()}</li>
 </ul>
```

You can try your example live at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#fQYhs9ga8WtwEr3ybERv9hftRnw=
Instructions on how to install the XQuery extension with PHP are available at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/entry/2011/12/27/PHP_Meets_XQuery

Comment: The links are failed.